# Azure DevOps Pipeline: Is it possible to deploy the build to other Services than Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, cicd

Is it possible to deploy a build, in my case in PHP, to other Hosting Service (e.g. cloudways)? Couldn't find anything in the Web.
If not, is it possible with Github?

Comment: I'm not familiar with cloudways, but in general it depends on what APIs or CLIs the provider makes available for deploying code. If you can deploy via API or from bash or powershell, you can automate it via DevOps.

Comment: Do you have any link where it gets explained how to do it?

Comment: found an example for digital ocean for everyone who is interested: https://www.bradcypert.com/deploying-from-azure-devops-to-digitalocean/